# AsyncTask Android in For Structure

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to implement something like the following on Android:

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    //a,b.. are changing
    aTask = new myAsyncTask(a,b..);
    aTask.execute();

    //Code to wait for myAsyncTask to finish


}
```

The problem is how can I wait for myAsyncTask to finish before starting the new iteration. One possible solution I thought is to put a Handler inside to wait for some seconds. For example:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 

    } 
}, 5000);
```

But this is not right even if it is working, because you have to put a standard time to wait for myAsyncTask. And it isn't sure if myAsyncTask finishes early or late because the a,b.. parameters change in every iteration.

Another solution I thought is to ask every time in a loop the object aTask to get the Status of myAsyncTask and check if it is FINISHED. For example:

```
while(!aTask.getStatus().equalsTo(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)){

}
```

But this isn't working because myAsyncTask is always RUNNING.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why not put the loop in the AsyncTask?

Comment: @DanS What do you mean by putting the loop in the AsyncTask?

Comment: Instead of iterating in the UI thread put the for loop in the execute portion of `myAsyncTask`.

Comment: @DanS Sorry, my friend I still don't understand. Can you be more specific by showing me how? Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeMelidis Dan is refering to my answer. have a look at Varargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //Code to wait for myAsyncTask to finish
```

If you wait there, you would freeze the UI. What is the point of another thread if you plan on waiting?

My guess what you need is to make use of the [optional parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) in the [execute(Params...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) method. You can put your 'a','b' or what ever those objects are and how many you put doesn't matter. This will allow your task to execute all of them and have better contorl.

```
protected Long doInBackground(Objects... objs){
    for(int i = 1; i < objs.length; i++){
       // Do Work
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I understood what you are saying. I didn't see it. I think this will help me. I will try it. The point is that I pass different images(bitmaps) and make some processing on them. So as you say I can put them in Params and handle them in the doInBackRound.

Comment: yes. the amount of bit maps doesn't matter. task.execute(b1,b2,b3,b4); you can pass any amount to it, and it will be passed to doInBackGround's `params`, use it like an  array of obj and the code that dan provided in my answer to iterate.

Comment: and Dan S Thanks a lot for your help. Finally I managed to do it with your advices. My code now is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

In Android you must not stay in the UI Thread and wait for something. This includes waiting for AsyncTasks that run in the background. If you would wait in the calling Thread, it would block the user and would freeze your device.

You must separate the code into two pieces.

First start the `AsyncTask`s:

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    //a,b.. are changing
    aTask = new myAsyncTask(a,b..);
    aTask.execute();

    // dont wait here. It would freeze the UI Thread
}
```

Second run code when Task has finished just overwrite the `onPostExecute()` method in `MyAsyncTask`.

Then Android can do its work while the AsyncTasks run.

Comment: With the handler the UI isn't freezing! The problem is that when the next iteration starts creates a new AsyncTask and the app crashes. OnPostExecute what I can do? I didn't understand!

Comment: Well, the question is, what you want to do after one of the tasks has finished? The Handler would not freeze, because you would not wait in the for-loop where the comment is, right? The solution is straight forward: Whatever you would code in the `run()` method of the `Handler` you simply write into the `onPostExecute()` method in the `AsyncTask`. See [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for an explanation and example. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

a simple suggestion, depending on what your for loop is actually doing, is to use the loop to create a 'queue' of items you want processed. then, fire off an asynctask with the first object in the queue, and upon completion of that task, fire off the next object in the queue until the length of your queue is zero

Answer (score 0):

The `easiest` way is to create a method from where you call `asynTask.execute()` and call that method from `onPostExecute()`.

```
public class ParentClass extends Activity
{

   int asyncCalls = 0;
   ......


    public void callAsyncTaskAgain()
    {
      aTask = new myAsyncTask(a,b..);
      aTask.execute();

      asyncCalls++;
    }


    public class AnotherClass extends AsyncTask
    {

         protected Void onPostExecute(Void result)
         {
            ....

            if(asyncCalls < SOME_NUMBER)
                  callAsyncTaskAgain();
    }
}
```

}

Hope this helps